# Solving a higer order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $n=1,2,3\dots$

Discuss how the observations
$D^n(x^{n-1})=0$ and $D^n(x^n)=n!$ can be used to find the general
solutions of the given differential equations.

1. $y''=0$
2. $y'''=0$
3. $y(4)=0$
4. $y''=2$
5. $y'''=6$
6. $y(4)=24$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?
Please note that Math.SE is not a homework site.
You should show your effort to solve the problem and address some conceptual problems that you are trying to tackle. In this way, the community can help you understand the problems, instead of solving them for you.

Comment: I don't understand how the given conditions can help solve the given problems?

Comment: I think superposition principle would be applied, but how will i get there from the given conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Waheguru ji ka khalsa, waheguru ji ki fateh.

$$
D^n\left(x^n\right) = n!\\
D^n\left(x^{n-1}\right) = 0\\
$$
then we can find
$$
y'' = 0\tag{1}
$$
$$
y''' = 6.\tag{2}
$$
we can solve the first one we know that the highest order of Eq. 1 is $n-1 = 2-1 = 1$ i.e.
$$
y = x + c\
$$
for the second one we know that $3! = 6$ this means the highest order is $x^3$ so we find
$$
y = x^3 + a_1x^2 + a_2x + a_3
$$

Comment: I think "ji ji" should be "ji ki".

Comment: oops..and I call myself a Sikh.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1.**

Consider equation number $2$. Since its third derivative is constantly zero, the solution must be a polynomial of degree $d<3$: otherwise, the derivative would not be constantly zero.

**Example 2.**

Consider equation number $5$. This time, its third derivative is constantly $6$. This has a correlation with the leading coefficient of the polynomial: integrating it shows that its leading term's coefficient is $\frac{6}{3!}=1$

This leads to

**Theorem**: A solution to the equation $y^{(n)}=a$ for $n\geq1$ is:

1. A polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $d=n$ with leading coefficient $L_c=\frac{a}{n!}$ if $a\neq0$
2. A polynomial $Q(x)$ of degree $d\leq n-1$ if $a=0$

**Proof**:

1.

> Using that $D^n(x^{n})=n!$, we calculate the $n$-th derivative of $P(x)$ and obtain
>   $$P^{(n)}(x)=(L_cx^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_ix^i)^{(n)}=n!L_c=n!\frac{a}{n!}=a$$
>
> Hence, $P(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation.

2.

> Using that $D^n(x^{n-1})=0$, we calculate the $n$-th derivative of $Q(x)$ and obtain
>   $$Q^{(n)}(x)=(\sum_{i=0}^{d} c_ix^i)^{(n)}=0$$
>   because $d\leq n-1$. Hence, $Q(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation.

Comment: When i integrate both of them, i get D^n*x^n=0. But I don't know how to use this condition further.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise. I meant in the differential equations 1 through 6.

Comment: Should i integrate both sides with respect to x?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. Yes, you should integrate with respect to $x$.

Comment: Thanks for showing me an example. The integration gives us a solution but where does the given condition help us ?                                                                          For example If we put n=1 in D^n*x^(n-1), then we get y^1=0 which in turn implies that c1=0 in your first integration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i only get to use internet connection for a limited time during the day.

Comment: I added a thorough explanation that does not use integration, but only the given information. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, the explanation helped me a lot.